# PHP: %-sign in string?

Tags: php

I have gotten a PHP script which uses an array to store configuration data, like `$config["maxPosts"] = 5;`.
Some of the settings need to be given as a string. In an example file, that looks like this:

```
$config["welcomeMsg"] = "Welcome home, %name%";
```

What does the `%` mean in that case?

Comment: Probably for string formatting - `%name%` would be replaced by the username.

Comment: Is it, by any chance, `phpBB`?

Comment: No, it's not phpBB. When it's a placeholder, why not write $config["welcomeMsg"] = "Welcome home, " . $name; or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the `%name%` is just a placeholder, which will get replaced later in the script.